# why is the first parameter(addr) of linux syscall futex different user-space and kernel-space

Tags: android, linux, system-calls

I print the addr in user-space when I call futex. Actually in pthread_mutex_lock.

```
__libc_format_log(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "jjkkll1", "addr:(%p,%p) val:%x owner_tid:%d onwer_tid:%d ", &mutex->state,mutex, mutex->state, owner_tid,mutex->owner_tid);
if (__futex_wait_ex(&mutex->state, shared, locked_contended, use_realtime_clock,
                        abs_timeout_or_null) == -ETIMEDOUT) {
        return ETIMEDOUT;
}
```

and print the uaddr in kernel

```
static int futex_wait(u32 __user *uaddr, unsigned int flags, u32 val,
          ktime_t *abs_time, u32 bitset)
{
    ...
    printk(KERN_WARNING "ljyfutex %p\n", uaddr);
    ...
}
```

but the value in user-space and kernel is diffrent.
I have no idea why?

Comment: I know why，it my fault. And compare with pthread_cond_internal_t and pthread_mutex_internal_t pointer

Comment: Could linux kernel distinguish pthread_cond and pthread mutex?